# Issues converting "controller as" syntax to classic $scope

Tags: angularjs

I have had major issues trying to convert my code from "controller as/this" syntax to classic $scope syntax, without breaking the code. I tried simply replacing "this" with $scope and removing the "controller as" assignments for both controllers, with no luck. I have created a jsfiddle for this with the controller as/this syntax so you can see how it should be working correctly prior to converting the syntax to $scope. https://jsfiddle.net/6zk9vujo/6/ 
This is another jsfiffle showing the broken code, when I simply replace _this with $scope and remove the controller as assignments in the html https://jsfiddle.net/6zk9vujo/12/ Thank you for your help in advance.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainController as main">
        <h2>
  Main Controller
  </h2>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="product in main.items">
                    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.price | currency}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button ng-click="main.increaseItemAmount(product)">
                            +
                        </button>
                        {{product.quantity}}
                        <button ng-click="main.decreaseItemAmount(product)">
                            -
                        </button>
                        <button ng-click="main.addToCart(product)">
                            Add to Cart
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="cartController as cart">
        <h2>
  Cart Controller
  </h2>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Item</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="product in cart.cartStorage.items">
                    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.price | currency}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button ng-click="cart.increaseItemAmount(product)">
                            +
                        </button>
                        {{product.quantity}}
                        <button ng-click="cart.decreaseItemAmount(product)">
                            -
                        </button>
                        <button ng-click="cart.removeFromCart(product)">
                            Remove from Cart
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
angular.module('app', [])
.factory('cartStorage', function() {
    var _cart = {
        items: []
    };
    var service = {
        get cartItems() {
            return _cart;
        }
    }
    return service;
})
.controller('mainController', function(cartStorage) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.cartStorage = cartStorage.cartItems;

    _this.items = [{
        name: 'Apple',
        price: 2.5,
        quantity: 1
    }];

    _this.addToCart = function(product) {
        _this.cartStorage.items.push(product);
        product.addedToCart = true;
    }

    _this.increaseItemAmount = function(product) {
        product.quantity++;
        product.showAddToCart = true;
    }

    _this.decreaseItemAmount = function(item) {
        product.quantity--;
        if (product.quantity <= 0) {
            product.quantity = 0;
            product.addedToCart = false;
            product.showAddToCart = false;
            var itemIndex = _this.cartStorage.items.indexOf(product);
            if (productIndex > -1) {
                _this.cartStorage.items.splice(productIndex, 1);
            }
        } else {
            product.showAddToCart = true;
        }
    }
})
.controller('cartController', function(cartStorage) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.cartStorage = cartStorage.cartItems;

    _this.increaseItemAmount = function(item) {
        product.quantity++;
    }

    _this.decreaseItemAmount = function(item) {
        item.quantity--;
        if (item.quantity <= 0) {
            item.quantity = 0;
            item.addedToCart = false;
            item.showAddToCart = false;
            var productIndex = _this.cartStorage.items.indexOf(item);
            if (productIndex > -1) {
                _this.cartStorage.items.splice(productIndex, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    _this.removeFromCart = function(item) {
        item.quantity = 0;
        item.addedToCart = false;
        item.showAddToCart = false;
        var productIndex = _this.cartStorage.items.productOf(item);
        if (productIndex > -1) {
            _this.cartStorage.items.splice(productIndex, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You should probably state what problems you were having

Comment: Why do you need to convert in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl, my current codebase in my application is not in "controller as/this" syntax, and using this code makes things really hard for me to understand, while integrating it with the rest of my code. I have been stuck working with it for DAYS. My codebase uses classic $scope everywhere.

Comment: Your original code is quite broken. You should have at least got that working before posting your *question*

Comment: I actually just realized that after the fact. I had a number of different JSFiddles in my browser while playing with the code, and it seems that I had mistakingly added that slightly broken version. I apologize for that. Thank you for fixing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template, remove all `main.` and `cart.` and change to `ng-controller="mainController"` and `ng-controller="cartController"`.

In your controllers, inject `$scope` and assign it to `_this` for easiest migration.

```
.controller('mainController', function($scope, cartStorage) {
    var _this = $scope;
```

and

```
.controller('cartController', function($scope, cartStorage) {
    var _this = $scope;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6zk9vujo/10/

---

Alternatively, just replace all `_this` references with `$scope` in your controllers.

You also have a bunch of mixed up `product` / `item` and `productIndex` / `itemIndex` variables. I've standardised them all in this fiddle as well as fixed the logic around re-adding the same product.

https://jsfiddle.net/6zk9vujo/13/

Comment: I appreciate your help Phil, but I am trying to get rid the use of the keyword "this" in this code completely and only use the classic AngularJS style that existed before contoroller as syntax came into vogue, using "$scope" only. For example instead of it reading:   "_this.addToCart = function(product) {...." I want it to read  _"$scope.addToCart = function(product) {...." Are you able to modify the jsfiddle to show $scope without using the keywords "this", "vm" or  "controller as" syntax? Thanks.

Comment: @user791134 why? `_this` is just a variable and is in no way related to `this` (the controller instance). If you must, just do a search / replace for `_this` to `$scope` in your controllers

Comment: Phil. Please see this new jsfiddle with everything refactored as we discussed. https://jsfiddle.net/6zk9vujo/12/ It has broken the code. Thanks.

Comment: @user791134 yes, you had bad code as well as some bad logic around re-adding the same product to the cart. I've fixed it all above

Comment: Thank you sir!!! This solved the issue. You are right there was a bug issue in that version of the my jsfiddle. Thank you for identifying that as well!

Answer (score -1):

It will work if you remove the "as" syntax when you define the controller in the view: `ng-controller="mainController"` and `ng-controller="cartController"`.

Edited: I made a mistake of putting the wrong fiddle link.

https://jsfiddle.net/analiza641/jr0stbLq/3/

Comment: I appreciate your input Alex, but that does not solve the issue for me. I have already tried that and replacing _this with $scope and it breaks the code, hence why I am asking for help on here. Also your jsfiddle is the exact same as mine and is not showing any changes. Thanks again.

Comment: I was wondering why I was downvoted so thanks for pointing it out..It seems like I haven't saved my draft of my answer.I updated the link but I think it's too late. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No prob. Just so you are aware I was not the one who did the downvote! I will admit, I also personally don't like people downvoting my questions/answers on here without pointing out the reason for doing so either. Regardless, keep on coding! :)